Unity 2D Rotar 90 grados
Gracia de antemano,
Quiero que mi personaje rote 90 grados cada vez que presiono las flechas de dirección y la flecha hacia arriba siempre mueva el personaje en la dirección en que se encuentre...


Hola Gerson, bienvenido, los textos no van en imagenes, si recibes un mensaje de error, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines la imagen y agregues el código y el mensaje de error, como texto, así evitarás el cierre de la misma y recibir votos negativos.
